# Resources and info on Windows 8 programing with C++ \ XAML for Metro

Tags: c++, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Are there any good quality resources on Windows 8 programing using C++ \ XAML for the Metro style? I'm interested in some good tutorials or articles.

I have searched web, but I couldn't find any good resources except the MSDN ones. There are a few articles about the javaScript development under WinRT and Metro, but seemingly there are no such things for C++ developers yet. Just several really simple tutorials.

Do you know any useful links or resources to learn from?

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a Recommendation Engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/172496)

Comment: @BrianRoach got that. I've edited the question. But the question isn't about some subjective estimations of some resources. There are to few resources at all. So I would appreciate any which can be useful. Currently I have only MSDN to look into.

Comment: I fail to see the specific programming question or code you're having a problem with? As the link to the meta points out, unfortunately this site isn't for recommendations.

Comment: @Occulta: [Stack Overflow is also not a *search* engine.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128549/164572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should watch Build videos, read blogs and find people who talk winrt on twitter. You can check [winrtppl.com](http://winrtppl.com), [winrtdaily.com](http://winrtdaily.com), [silverlightshow.net](http://silverlightshow.net), [timheuer.com](http://timheuer.com), [windowsdevnews.com](http://windowsdevnews.com) but there are a lot more.

Comment: I suppose you could also check out the Pluralsight videos. They have a free trial if you don't have an account.